# ComboBox Index and PK MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Title is a bit weird.
Problem I am facing is that, I get the records from database, and add the records in comboBox, but when I want to delete the records from there, I get ID from index number of comboBox, e.g (primary key = indexNumber of ComboBox),
If ID no.1 gets deleted,then in database ID starts from 2, but index of comboBox again starts from 2. So then lets say I want to delete IndexNo 3,but in database ID no. 2 will be deleted.

I hope you get the point.

Here is the code to get ID no.

```
 int ID = (cmboBoxClient.SelectedIndex) + 1;  
 // as ID in SQL starts from 1(Identity(1,1))

 SQLQuery = "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE CustID = '" + ID + "'";
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check my answer ?? did it help you?

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `Combobox`'s `DataSource` you should also specify `DisplayMember` and [`ValueMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.dynamics.mobile.framework.controls.combobox.valuemember.aspx) like this:

```
cmboBoxClient.DataSource = yourDataTable;
cmboBoxClient.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmboBoxClient.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Then you can find the valid `ID` with `SelectedValue` like this:

```
int ID = (int) cmboBoxClient.SelectedValue;
```